# Prove an upper bound for the multiplicative order of a congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

This is a problem from elementary Number Theory. It's the only one I couldn't figure out and it's bothering me.

Definition: Let a and n be natural numbers with (a, n) = 1. The smallest natural number **k** such that **a<sup>k</sup> ≡ 1 (mod n)** is called the order of **a** modulo **n** and is denoted **ord<sub>n</sub>(a).**

Prove:
Let **a** and **n** be natural numbers with (a, n) = 1. Then **ord<sub>n</sub>(a) < n.**

Comment: Hint: pigeonhole the powers $\,a^k\,$ to find two congruent powers $\, a^k\equiv a^j,\ 0\le j < k < n.\ $  By $\,(a,n)=1\,$ you can $j$ times cancel $\,a\,$ to get $\,a^{k-j}\equiv 1.\ \ $